# webkit-overflow-scrolling: get Y position

Tags: css

How can I get the `Y` position of this scroll?

```
.cool-scroll{
overflow-y:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

My intention is to change the background color when it exceeds `N` value of `Y` Axis.

Comment: You may need to use javascript or jQuery.

Comment: hi thank you, do I have to use .css() ? @user1671639

Comment: Nope `.scroll` will help you.  let me give a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using jQuery, the code will listen to the scroll event on the element and apply a new class when the target position has been reached

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEKEq/)**

**Javascript**

```
var targetScroll = 200;
$('.cool-scroll').scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > targetScroll)
        $(this).addClass('scrolled');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('scrolled');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.cool-scroll.scrolled{
    background: red;
}
```